# Head is undefined when trying to create a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list for a project. I've got these two file (one .h and one .cpp). I'm not sure how to make a copy constructor so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. I suppose if someone wanted to point me in the right direction on that as well, it would be helpful. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "studentList.h"

using namespace std;

// Default Constructor for StudentList
// Creates Dummy Head Node for a new empty list
StudentList::StudentList ()
{
// Create the dummy head node
Node* Head;             // Creates Head Node
Head = new Node;        
Head->next = NULL;      // Sets pointer to NULL by default
}

//Copy Constructor
StudentList::StudentList(const StudentList& list)
{

}

void StudentList::addStudentList(Student newStudent)
{
```

Getting the error here!!!!!!

```
if (Head->next == NULL)
{
    Head->next->student = newStudent;
    Head->next->prev = Head;
    Head->next->next = NULL;
}
}
```

Here is the .h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;


class StudentList{

public:
//Default Constructor
StudentList();
//Copy Constructor
StudentList(const StudentList& list);
//Add Student Method
void addStudentList(Student);


private:
// Node struct to hold Student data and with pointers to a previous and next node in linked list
struct Node {
Student student;
Node* prev;
Node* next;
};

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Head` is supposed to be a member. The pointer `Head` you create has automatic storage. It goes out of scope when the constructor is finished, and you get a dangling reference.

```
class StudentList{

public:
//Default Constructor
  StudentList();
//Copy Constructor
  StudentList(const StudentList& list);
//Add Student Method
  void addStudentList(Student);


private:
// Node struct to hold Student data and with pointers to a previous and next node in linked list
  struct Node {
    Student student;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
  };

  Node* Head;

};


StudentList::StudentList ()
{
  Head = new Node;        
  Head->next = NULL;      // Sets pointer to NULL by default
}
```

On a side note, you should indent the code you put between curly braces. It makes it easier fo the human reader to group related elements together, an to spot code blocks.

As for the copy c'tor, as you can see, it takes a reference to an existing object, and constructs a new one out of it. The defaulut copy c'tor supplied by the compiler does a shallow copy. Meaning is `a` and `b` are lists, than `a.Head` and `b.Head` point to the same starting elements. You can overrride it to do a deep copy with something like this:

```
StudentList::StudentList(const StudentList& list)
{
  Node* Head = new Node;
  Node* tmp = Head;
  Node* iter = list.Head;
  while (iter)
  {
    *tmp = *iter;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if (iter->next)
      tmp->next = new Node;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    iter = iter->next;
  }
}
```

I of course neglected `tmp->prev` but that's the general idea for a signly linked list.

Comment: I appreciate your response. It helped a lot. I did indent originally but when posting here, I guess that didn't transfer.

Comment: Also if you have any idea where I can learn about copy constructors and how to build one for linked lists that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure I get the purpose of the copy constructor in general

Comment: @cadavid4j, Like the name implies it's used to create new objects out of existing objects. It gets called when you pass or return something by value, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

this here

```
StudentList::StudentList ()
{
// Create the dummy head node
Node* Head;             // Creates Head Node
Head = new Node;        
Head->next = NULL;      // Sets pointer to NULL by default
}
```

is making a local variable in ctor that ceases to exist after the StudentList is constructed. You need to move out the `Head` so that it becomes a class member i.e. in the header file declare it

```
class StudentList {
..
Node* Head;
};
```

so your constructor instead looks like

```
StudentList::StudentList ()
{
// Create the dummy head node
Head = new Node;        
Head->next = NULL;      // Sets pointer to NULL by default
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Do you have any idea what they copy constructor should look like. I'm not asking for code but maybe a place I could look to see how to make one.

Comment: It is a bit tricky with the copy constructor in this case because you are dealing with raw pointers so you need to *clone* the node instead of just copying it.